# How to choose icons with same name in React Native Vector Icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am making my first React Native app, and I would like to add some icons in my buttons, so [I installed React Native Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios), and use it in my code, like this: `<IconButton icon='cart-plus' color='blue' />`.

The problem is that I can see in React Native Vector Icons directory that there are many icons with the same name:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to specify which is the one I want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to import the correct icon component like below

```
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = <FontAwesome name="cat-plus" size={30} color="#900" />;

import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
const myIcon = <FontAwesome5 name="cat-plus" size={30} color="#900" />;
```